# How to identify all columns which are causing data type error in T-SQL Union?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to perform union on two large tables (over 600 columns). All variables in both tables are supposed to have same format, but they were prepared separately by two different teams.

```
SELECT * into #FINAL_TABLE
from 
(select * from Table1
UNION
select * FROM Table2 ) as tmp
```

I get an error which includes information about error in data types in one column:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 600 
> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Base on that error I can't say:

1. Which column is causing the error?
2. Are there others columns which are also causing mismatch error?

Is there more efficient way to identify all columns which are causing date type mismatch error then checking column by column?

Comment: Hello. There are several remarks to make: (1) Having 600 columns in a table reeks of a database that isn't normalized, (2) Never write `SELECT *` queries unless in very specific circumstances, and this isn't one, (3) Make sure that data is put in columns with the appropriate data type (integer in INT columns, date in DATE columns, etc).

Comment: If you union the tables, the columns have to be in the same order as well (another reason why `*` is advised against). You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` system view to compare the column datatypes and order.

Comment: @TT. Thanks for your comment. (1) I can't change that, the next step in process is exporting that table to CSV and importing it to specific software. (2). Fair point. (3). Ok, but that is still column by column solution.

Comment: Aside: [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will remove duplicate rows with some penalty in performance. If that isn't needed, i.e. you know there are no duplicates, then use `union all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should identify data type mismatches between the two tables.

```
SELECT 
  IST1.COLUMN_NAME as Table1_column
  ,IST1.DATA_TYPE as Table1_datatype
  ,IST2.COLUMN_NAME as Table2_column
  ,IST2.DATA_TYPE as Table2_datatype
FROM information_schema.columns IST1
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns IST2 
  ON IST1.ORDINAL_POSITION=IST2.ORDINAL_POSITION
WHERE IST1.table_name='Table1' AND IST1.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
AND IST2.table_name='Table2' AND IST2.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
AND IST1.DATA_TYPE <> IST2.DATA_TYPE
```

Comment: This query is not correct, because it will returns false "false"... Like if column of IST1 is a datetime and column os IST2 is DATETIME2 or for NCHAR/NVARCHAR/CHAR/VARCHAR. You must not have IST1.DATA_TYPE <> IST2.DATA_TYPE but something that use a CASE with the "familly" of the data type, not the datatype!

Comment: You are correct, the are are conversions that are possible so the datatypes do not have to be exact matches. However the person asking the question said Table1 and Table2 should be basically the same. I just provided a quick query for him to check the validity of that statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, that will return the table and column names where the data type is inconsistent. But the points in the comments really stand here:

- You should be *explicitly* defining your columns in the `SELECT`, not using `SELECT *`
- Having 600 columns in a single table is certainly a design flaw, and should be addressed. Especially when you want to `UNION` that data

Also, if you are unioning the data, I suspect you want `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. I *doubt* any of your rows are going to be duplicates here as:

1. You have 600 columns, meaning all *600* needs to be identical on 2 separate rows
2. Your 2 tables have different definitions, meaning that the 2 tables *can't* have duplicates.

Anyway, one way would be to use `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` to get the details of the returned result sets, and then compare the data types for columns in the same ordinal position from the 2 result sets.

```sql
SELECT T1.[name] AS Table1Column,
       T1.system_type_name AS Table1Type,
       T2.[name] AS Table2Column,
       T2.system_type_name AS Table2Type
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT * FROM Table1;',NULL,NULL) T1
     JOIN sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Table2;',NULL,NULL) T2 ON T1.column_ordinal = T2.column_ordinal
WHERE T1.system_type_id <> T2.system_type_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2017 and upper :

```
DECLARE @SomeString varchar(100) = 'ABC_DEF_GHI_jkl';
WITH T0 AS
(
SELECT 1 AS INDICE, 
       SUBSTRING(@SomeString, 1, 1) AS RAW_LETTER, 
       SUBSTRING(UPPER(@SomeString), 1, 1) AS UP_LETTER
UNION ALL
SELECT INDICE + 1, 
       SUBSTRING(@SomeString, INDICE + 1, 1) AS RAW_LETTER, 
       SUBSTRING(UPPER(@SomeString), INDICE + 1, 1)
FROM   T0
WHERE  INDICE < LEN(@SomeString)
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(RAW_LETTER, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY INDICE)
FROM   T0
WHERE  RAW_LETTER COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = UP_LETTER;
```

For SQL Server previous than 2017 :

```
WITH T0 AS
(
SELECT 1 AS INDICE, 
       SUBSTRING(@SomeString, 1, 1) AS RAW_LETTER, 
       SUBSTRING(UPPER(@SomeString), 1, 1) AS UP_LETTER
UNION ALL
SELECT INDICE + 1, 
       SUBSTRING(@SomeString, INDICE + 1, 1) AS RAW_LETTER, 
       SUBSTRING(UPPER(@SomeString), INDICE + 1, 1)
FROM   T0
WHERE  INDICE < LEN(@SomeString)
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '' + RAW_LETTER
              FROM   T0
              WHERE  RAW_LETTER COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN = UP_LETTER
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '');
```